# Can ping anther PC is same network connected by switch

Tags: networking, ip, ping

I have two PC in same subnet and connected via switch. When I do arp -a the other IP address is shown but I cant ping the other PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is shown in `arp`, but maybe it is cached, and currently not reachable. Try the following command, which outputs its current cache state:

```
ip neigh
```

For example, on my personal laptop, I have a wireless adapter (`wlan0`) and a wired one (`eth0`), both connected to the same network (my home router). With `arp -a` it displays

```
? (192.168.1.1) en xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] en wlan0
? (192.168.1.1) en xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] en eth0
```

and with `ip neigh` it shows

```
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx STALE
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx REACHABLE
```

As seen with `ip neigh`, the wireless one is in the `STALE` state, cause it is not being used, but `arp -a` does not displays it.